# EasyPHP starting error after trying to change PHP

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

I have been using EasyPHP-12.1 for some years now but, foolishly, tried to add a different version of PHP. (I had backed up the www files but not the whole installation). I added a new version (5.6.21) to the PHP folder, selected it in the admin but it didn't work. Now the server doesn't start. It comes up with the error:

```
Error in Apache configuration file: AH00526: Syntax error on line 185 
of C:/Server/EasyPHP/apache/conf/httpd.conf: invalid command "PHPIniDir", 
perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included 
in the server configuration.
```

I would like to go back to the original PHP (5.4.6) or, at least, reinstall the program and copy the MySQL databases to the new installation. As I said, I have copies of all the working php pages - it's the databases that I am worried about losing.

I hope someone can get me up and running again.

Comment: What is `"PHPIniDir"` set to in `C:/Server/EasyPHP/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: PHPIniDir "${path}/apache

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have managed to get it all working again. I found an earlier dated backup in the conf folder, renamed it and restarted. Phew! 
*(Made sure I am backing up all the databases and EasyPHP folder now.)*